# a simple way in java template function like cpp

Tags: java, templates

how could i use template in java?
say an array sum function in cpp may like:

```
template <typename T>
T sum (T *array, const int length) {
  if (length <= 0) return (T) 0;
  T res = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) res += array[i];
  return res;
}
```

therefore i can use sum in such way:

```
sum (float *);
sum (double *);
sum (long *);
```

I've tried  `class name<T>` here, but need to much code; also hard to work for `int, float, long, double`
so how to do like this in java?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: They are different languages, and Java just does not work that way.

Comment: In Java you don't really need a function to do that: if it's an array of integers for example you can do in a one-liner: `Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()` if it's `Long`: `Arrays.stream(arr).mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum()` and etc.